# Scanf - the introduction of value and arithmetic

Tags: c

I have simple problem ;) When i enter the number 0.2,  the result is 0.2. When i enter the operation 1/5 or 1.0/5.0, the result is 1. Can you explain?

```
float a;
printf("Enter the number:");
scanf("%f",&a);
printf("%f",a);
printf("\n");
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `scanf` doesn't perform arithmetic operations, and it doesn't recognize fractions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you type `1/5` for the `scanf`, the `scanf` scans `1`, sees the `/` and as it is not a valid character for `%f`, stops scanning, leaving the rest of the data in the `stdin`.

Similarly, When you type `1.0/5.0` for the `scanf`, the `scanf` scans `1.0` sees the `/` and as it is not a valid character for `%f`, stops scanning, leaving the rest of the data in the `stdin`.

Note that `scanf` is not `eval` (`eval` is a function in python) and simply scans data from the `stdin`.

Answer (score 3):

`scanf` isn't capable of parsing a term and evaluating it. In your case, it reads just the leading `1` and returns that in `a`:

To read a term like yours, you could use

```
double op1, op2, res;
char op;
scanf("%lf %c %lf", &op1, &op, &op2);
switch (op) {
case '/':
    res = op1 / op2;
/* and so on... */
}
```

For more sophisticated terms you need a more sophisticated parser. Bjarne Stroustrup describes an easy but clever and flexible one  in his book "The C++ Programming Language", for example.